# How to split on number>letter or letter>number

Tags: c#, regex

I need something like this:

```
test123tersre23
```

to turn into something like this:

```
{"test", "123", "tersre", "23"}
```

I've seen lots of solutions using groups, but I need to use Regex.Split here (as I already have some other custom splitting logic in it).

Any help?

Comment: Does your input always contains only 2 strings and 2 numbers?

Comment: I'd probably do this with my own logic. It's easier to just convert to a char array, parse til you hit the opposite of what you're on, then take substring.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek No, it can be anything.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I would, but I've already built the rest of it around regexes.

Comment: You're unlikely to get a good solution if you begin by choosing the tool you're going to use regardless of its fitness for the problem.

Comment: @EricLippert That's true, actually. But I did manage to get a solution.

Comment: @Downvoter PLEASE EXPLAIN WHY. I can't make the question better if you don't tell me why it's bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookaround assertions for the splitting:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split("test123tersre23", @"(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)");
```

This has the effect of splitting on the void (empty space) between the characters being sought by the assertions.

Comment: Works: gives me double items, but I can just delete those. Thanks!

Comment: @ofstream Not sure I understand where "double items" would be coming from. It seems to work fine for me with your example.

Comment: It's probably my own fault, but empty items can be ignored anywasy. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Regex.split(input, "(\d+)");
```

With one set of capturing parentheses, it should output any series of digits as delimiters, per [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4).  This makes some assumptions about exactly how you intend to parse, but seems like the right idea, anyway.

---

Baseed on comments below, you are looking for something like

```
@"($|%|\d+)"
```

Comment: What do capturing parentheses mean in a `Split` call? *edit Never mind.

Comment: That's doubling numbers: if I add it to my existing regex (something like @"($|%|(\d+))" (and more) and I give it an input of numbersomethingnumber it gives me number,number,something,number,number

Comment: @ofstream Are you looking for some regex fragment to add to your existing regex?  That would be pertinent information, I think, which you are still witholding at least some of by the sound of it.  This does indeed work differently with multiple capturing groups, but it actually becomes simpler, if you had bothered to provide that from the start.

Comment: @femtoRgon Actually, in the question: "I've seen lots of solutions using groups, but I need to use Regex.Split here (as I **already have some other custom splitting logic** in it)." It hasn't been edited.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the regular expression you're looking for:

> \d+|\D+

Then, use the [**Regex.Matches**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) method to get the results. The code would look like this:

```
var input = "test123tersre23"
var pattern = @"\d+|\D+"
var results = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
```

This result contains a [**MatchCollection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.aspx). Loop through them to get the values:

```
foreach(Match m in results)
{
    var current = m.Value;
}
```

**Edit:**

Sorry, didn't see you required a solution with the Split method, I apologize.